# How we can auto re-enroll android devices after the factory reset without Zero Touch Portal account

Tags: android, mdm, google-cloud-identity, android-enterprise, android-enterprise-features

I want that if someone completes a hard reset on the Android device, then the device re-enrolled automatically by their serial number. The zero-touch portal provides this feature but we are trying without a portal

I already apply the zero touch portal but no response from google